# If statement with multiple conditions using two arrays - python

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements, multiple-conditions

I'm having trouble constructing an if statement that applies multiple conditions with two arrays.

I would like to check two conditions whereby if the answer is True to either of these conditions then the first formula will be used otherwise the second formula will be used. I would like to do this cycling through 2 arrays and storing the values as I go.

The error I get is:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
> ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Is the following the correct method to implement this or am I way off and should be using a for loop to go through the arrays?

```
u2 = [0.01, 0.04, 0.07, 0.04]
Bq = [10, 15, 25, 21]
Qp = [1, 2, 1, 2]
k1 = 2
k2 = 1   
    
if (u2 < 0.02 or Bq < 20):
            a = -np.log(Qp-Qp*Bq+1)/k1
        else:
            a = -np.log(Qp-Qp*Bq+1)/k2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Apologies I tried to simplify my code and ended up making it more confusing.

Comment: What is e.g. `u2 < 0.02` supposed to check for? If *any* element in the list is less than `0.02`? If *all* elements are? Something else? Same with `Bq < 20` of course.

Comment: Perhaps switch entirely to `np.array`s or data frames, whose semantics are probably closer to what you expect, instead of basic native Python arrays. You already seem to be using Numpy; perhaps also explore Pandas.

Comment: Your latest edit makes this less clear again. Comparing an array to a scalar is not well-defined.

Comment: Seems you trying to check the conditions element wise.  In which chase you should make `u2, Bq, Qp` numpy arrays. and use `result = np.where((u2 < 0.02) | (Bq < 20), -np.log(Qp-Qp*Bq+1)/k1, -np.log(Qp-Qp*Bq+1)/k2)`.  Issue beomes that `Qp-Qp*Bq+1` is negative for all elements which makes the log invalid e.g. `array([ -8, -27, -23, -39])`

Comment: On another note, the statement `-np.log(Qp-Qp*Bq+1)/k1` doesn't do anything useful. It does a calculation, but then throws away the result.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over both lists to check each and every value, you can't do it as a single expression.

You can use the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) functions to iterate over the two lists simultaneously:

```
for (u, b) in zip(u2, Bq):
    if u < 0.02 or b < 20:
        # TODO: Do something
    else:
        # TODO: Do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could technically use logical indexing to solve it.
I didn't check in detail if it is fully functional, but you could use something like this, since you are already using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
u2 = np.array([0.01, 0.04, 0.07, 0.04])
Bq = np.array([10, 15, 25, 21])
Qp = np.array([1, 2, 1, 2])
k1 = 2
k2 = 1   
logical_array=np.logical_or(u2 < 0.02,Bq < 20)
results=np.zeros(4)
results[logical_array]=-np.log(Qp[logical_array]-Qp[logical_array]*Bq[logical_array]+1)/k1
results[~logical_array]=-np.log(Qp[~logical_array]-Qp[~logical_array]*Bq[~logical_array]+1)/k2
```

Edit: I don't know what is going on in your formula, but it results in negative values for the logarithm. Be careful.